# I am not able to find age by using year in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, datediff, nvarchar

I am writing a query as following

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year,Clmn_Dob,getdate()) AS DiffDate 
FROM tblABCD
```

where `Clmn_Dob` is a `NVARCHAR` column. I want to find the age based on date of birth. But instead of this I am getting an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

My string format is `dd/MM/yyyy` and `getdate()` format is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

I do not get any solution

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATETIME` datatype! That allows you to then use date functions on your column.

Comment: i am actually use datetime datatype. but in this case i want like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONVERT function:

```
SELECT
DATEDIFF(year,CONVERT(datetime, Clmn_Dob, 103),getdate()),
FROM tblABCD
```

and here doc:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: So maybe your data in that column is corrupted? Are you sure that there are ONLY the dd/MM/yyyy strings there?

Comment: Ok. so maybe there are some not existing dates e.g. 33/01/2013 or 06/17/2013? How many entries do you have? Can you check every one for correct date?

Comment: 5000 entries are there...., can you split this string column into three columns based on '/'

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you have in mind, but you could use this:
SELECT MAX(x.DD), MAX(x.MM), MAX(x.YYYY) FROM (
SELECT
substring(Clmn_Dob, 1 ,2) as "DD",
substring(Clmn_Dob, 4 ,2) as "MM",
substring(Clmn_Dob, 7 ,4) as "YYYY"
FROM tblABCD
) x